# Cleanest way to run a bunch of boolean functions and return false if any of them are false?

Tags: java

I have this static utility that validates pojo data.

```
  isValid = validateFunc1(pojo1);
  isValid = validateFunc2(pojo1);
......
  return isValid;
```

> I could have as many as 10 validator functions, let's say.

Obviously this doesn't work because if func1 is false and func2 is true, the boolean is overwritten. My question is, I want to return false if *any* of the functions eval to false, otherwise return true.

Comment: Are you using Java8?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes and I could have many many functions which is why the OR isn't the best option

Comment: You might be able to create a `Predicate` list and iterate over that

Comment: If one function returns false, do you want to bother with the other functions?  Or do you want to return false immediately when that happens?

Comment: one function returning false is enough to kill execution

Comment: `isValid &= validateFunc2(pojo1);`?

Comment: Why not just `if (! validateFunc1(pojo1)) return false;`, repeated for the other functions, then `return true;` at the end?

Answer (score 3):

Any time you see repeated code like this, it's a good idea to ask whether replacing a bunch of repetition with a loop or equivalent (such as a stream operation) is worthwhile. This case is an excellent candidate:

```
interface Validator {
    boolean isValid(MyObject obj);
}


List<Validator> validators = getValidators();
return validators.stream().allMatch(v -> v.isValid(obj));
```

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, you put it to a higher level than me. :) +1

Comment: Why not a `Predicate<MyObject>`?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn It's perfectly fine to use a `Predicate` in this case, but I thought the example was clearer with a more specific type.

Comment: This is exactly what a `Predicate` is for - not so good to reinvent a wheel.  You can use a suitable variable name to make sure the intended use of the `Predicate` is clear.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Unless, of course, you're wanting to dependency-inject the implementations by type, or make sure that you have correct type constraints, or whatever. In this case in particular, the usual application of `allMatch` is inside out--we're iterating *over* a list of predicates--and having `Predicate` explicitly on both sides of `allMatch` is an opportunity for confusion for someone who's new to the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `&&` (`and`) operator. This one is short-circuited. It means if the left operand is evaluated `false`, then the right operand will not be evaluated at all, skipped.

```
return (validateFunc1(pojo1) && validateFunc2(pojo2));
```

Let's say you have provided a large number of boolean results. Use the cycle and stop the checking to make it like short-circuited. Let's define for brevity the array of your functions results first and perform the iteration.

```
// mock
boolean[] array = new boolean[] {true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true};

// iteration
boolean valid = true;
for (boolean b: array) {
    if (!valid) { break; }
    valid = valid && b;
}
```

I recommend you to manage the methods to be callable in the loop one-by-one. Then you won't need to validate all of them since one of them has already failed. However, you have to provide information about these validation methods first.

---

Personal suggestion:

For example, turn static methods into classes like `NameValidated`, `EmailValidated`... implementing `Validated` and stack them in the array to be looped:

```
for (Validated validated: arrayOfValidated) {
    if (!valid) { break; }
    valid = valid && validated.get();
}
```

Using classes over static methods has a bunch of advantages. If interested, read more at the article [OOP Alternative to Utility Classes](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html). I find this as the **cleanest** solution.

Comment: I could have many validator functions, so this cleanliness may not work

Comment: Then please include this information in your question. How many is "many"?

Comment: And maybe tell us what is the difference btw each function??

Answer (score 1):

Use &&: `return validateFunc1(pojo1) && validateFunc2(pojo1)`

Edit:

You could also do something like this:

```
public interface Validator {
    boolean validate(Pojo pojo);
}

public class ValidatorA implements Validator {
   @Override
   public boolean validate(Pojo pojo) {
       ...
   }
}

public StaticUtilityClass {
    private static final List<Validator> validators = ... ; // Add new ValidatorA(), new ValidatorB(), etc.

   ...
   Pojo pojo = ...;
   return validators.stream().allMatch(pojo::validate);
}
```

But this requires creating a class for each validator.

Comment: This only works if he doesn't want to run `validateFunc2()` if `validateFunc1()` fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run all the validators regardless (because they are logging, or otherwise generating a list of validation failures to notify about) and return a final result, then

```
boolean valid = validateFunc1(pojo);
valid = validateFunc2(pojo) && valid;
[...]
valid = validateFuncN(pojo) && valid;
return valid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are many functions, you could store the booleans in an arraylist, then iterate over the list. If at any point a boolean in the list is false, return false. If it runs over the list and none are false (all are true) return true:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

boolean isValid(){
    ArrayList<Boolean> bool_list=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    bool_list.append(validateFunc1(pojo1));
    bool_list.append(validateFunc2(pojo1));
    ...
    for(int i=0; i<bool_list.size(); i++){
        if(bool_list.get(i)==false){
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```